# Can't build artifacts (export JAR) in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-11

I am trying to create a .JAR out of my JavaFX project to then convert it into an .exe file. But IntelliJ doesn't show a "build artifacts" option in the main menu, which the guides I've seen require me to click. Build only gives me the following options: Recompile Main.java, Build Project, Rebuild Project 'Project Title'. Any help is appreciated

[I've already created an artifact in the project structure tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9sMw.png)

Comment: Try to install the latest IntelliJ IDEA version from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html and reset the menu customizations (if any): https://i.imgur.com/ubkXm2f.png .

Comment: I contacted JetBrains and they showed me how to reset menu customizations, that did it! The options were probably off because I had installed IntelliJ through and for a particular course. Thank you for the help, this was the solution!

Comment: Glad that it helped, the response you've got from JetBrains in the support ticket was from me as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must define an artifact in File > Project Structure > Artifacts. Once defined you can generate your final file under Build > Build artifacts > your_artifact

I leave you an example that I'm actually using
[image: eg]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the issue. I added an image to the original post to show how I've already created an artifact (I believe), and it still doesn't work. The image shows my Build menu.

Comment: Ok so the problem is that the menu voice is not available. As suggested from CrazyCoder, try to restore the defaults from Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars. Click on "+" icon > Add action > Main Menu > Build > Build Artifacts...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your IDE menu is customized and some of the items were removed. It should help if you either reset the menu to the defaults or add the missing items manually:

[image: Restore defaults]